# SSH “Could not open input file: bin/magento” in Magento2

Tags: magento2, third-party-module, command-line, ssh

I try to install: https://www.magesolution.com/front-end-cms-page-builder.html

in Magesolution document told run ssh command:

```
unzip -o Extension_Package_Name.zip
```

but the problem is when run `unzip -o Extension_Package_Name.zip` its told me this problem

http://prntscr.com/o5pttb

and then try to run :

```
php bin/magento module:enable MGS_Fbuilder
```

it shows me this error:

> Could not open input file: bin/magento

where is the problem?

First I run command `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` then `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` also I run command related cache, indexing but same error I get all the time.

can anyone tell me why is it happening ? and how to solve this error message?

I checked in Magento root folder that there is a bin folder and within bin folder, there is a Magento file.

Comment: Either check correct folder permissions or make sure you're in the magento root directory

Comment: permissions for what? and i upload magento to root in public_html

Comment: Permissions to bin/magento, also make sure when you ssh into your server that you `cd public_html` so you're in the magento root folder when running cli commands

Comment: @AJ47 yes i forget do this cd public_html

Comment: Make sure You're in your Magento root directory.. please run this command :- ls

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to confirm the command entered in the shell. The screenshot of your error message shows that the extract did not work.

Please make sure you paste the command once.

```
unzip -o Extension_Package_Name.zip
```

Now login as user in the shell and run- pwd

```
# pwd
/home/<username>/public_html
```

This will get you an idea of your present working directory.

Now, do an ls of bin/magento which the full path

```
# ls -l /home/<username>/public_html/bin/magento 
-rwxr--r-- 1 <username> <username> 799 Mar 26 14:26 /home/<username>/public_html/bin/magento
```

Now let see if php cli is working by php -v

```
# php -v
PHP 7.2.19 (cli) (built: Jun  3 2019 21:02:20) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader (enabled) + Intrusion Protection from ioncube24.com (unconfigured) v10.3.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by ionCube Ltd.
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.19, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

**Please get back with the output**

```
<username>  will need to be replaced with your sftp user.
```